# Google Map CodeName1 NullPointerException

Tags: codenameone

I am trying the Codenameone Google Maps library.

I am using only a single line of code:

```
  final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer("MAP KEY");
```

But this line returns this error :

```
An Internal application error occrred :java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.codename1.ui.Component.getAllStyles()' on a null object refrunce
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: i use eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `MAP KEY` to a valid JavaScript google maps key?

Did you define the build hint `javascript.googlemaps.key`?

Is your `build.xml` up to date (open Codename One Settings and save to check).

Comment: Thank you fro your answer , i make sure from all of this but the problem still exist this problem is appear  on my android phone ,, but on emulator the map  only work on desktop skin

Comment: The skin shouldn't impact the map at all. Are you sure the project is configured correctly? Are all libraries up to date?